# How to create dialogue node in watson conversation through java/ python sdk

Tags: dialog, watson-conversation, watson

I found in conversation SDK how to create entity, intents.But did not find any API to create dialogue node. Can anyone help me out with proper documentation?
I also posted a question in Watson-developer-cloud.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a dialog node is to create sample nodes you want in the conversation tooling.

Then using the workspace API you can export those nodes, and use them as a baseline to create others.

Looking at the Java SDK you would use `updateWorkspace()` method to push your changes to the workspace.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but should not it have another API to create dialogue, as we can create entity and dialogue !!

Comment: SDK's are always evolving and the ability to modify nodes through the workspace API relatively new. So it's likely you will be able to do this more granular at a later point. For the moment it's a node list you will need to change yourself.